# Meaning of asymptotically equal

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

I am familiar with the big-O notation. Today I attended a talk and the speaker used the following notation to say that $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are "of the same order":
$$
f(n) \sim g(n). \quad  (1)
$$
According to the definition that I found on Wikipedia, this means that
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 1$.
However, the speaker later on used that (1) implies that
$$
f(n) = g(n) + o(1), \quad (2)
$$
(or at least I *think* it was a little $o$ and not a big $O$ as the handwriting wasn't very clear).

Is there an easy proof that (1) implies (2)?

**Edit:**
As pointed out in the comments, this is not true. Does (1) instead imply the following:
$$
f(x) = g(x)(1 + o(1))
$$

Comment: This is the same as asserting that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=1\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)-g(n)=0 \, .
$$
It isn't true. Consider $f(n)=n+1$ and $g(n)=n$.

Comment: @Joe: I see. I suppose it does hold if it is $O(1)$ instead of little-o, right?

Comment: 'Functions $f$ and $g$ are asymptotically of the same order' may mean that $f/g\to 1$ or $|f(n)/g(n)|, |g(n)/f(n)|$ are bounded from above for big $n$ or $|f-g|$ is bounded from above or that $f(x)-g(x)\to 0$. You have to verify which definition is used by the speaker.

Answer (score 2):

Some definitions first:

$$
f(x) \in o(g(x)) \iff \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0.
$$

As the notion goes, I assume that by $f(x) = g(x)(1+o(1))$ we mean that

$$
f(x) - g(x) = g(x)t(x),
$$

where $t(x) \in o(1)$. In other words,

$$
\frac{f(x) - g(x)}{g(x)} \in o(1).
$$

Using the limit definition of $o(1)$, it is equivalent to

$$
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1.
$$